# how to set default la page as default in css

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have been struggled with one sticky issue regarding to set default li.

what I try to achieve is that set a li and its related page as default one. And when users click on others links, it would load other pages.

#### HTML Markup:

```
  <div id="productIntro">
     <div id="leftNav">
        <ul>
           <li class="head">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('.$row["id"].',1);"> Pictures</b></a>
           </li>
           <li class="head">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('.$row["id"].',2);"> <b>Comments</b></a>
           </li>
           <li class="head">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('.$row["id"].',3);"> <b>Others</b></a>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="main">
     </div>
  </div>
```

#### JS:

```
        function show(id, page) {
           $('.main').load("loadProDetail.php?id=" + id + "&page=" + page, true);
        }
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
           $(document).on('click', '.head', function () {
              $(".head").removeClass("selected");
              $(this).toggleClass("selected");
           });
        });
```

#### loadProDetail PHP

```
  <?php
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $sql = "select * from product where id=$id ";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $page = $_GET['page'];
  if($page == 1)
  {
     $html .= '<img src="./product_images/' . $row["name"] . '.jpg" width="150" border="2">';
  }
  if($page == 2)
  {
     $html .= 'No comments so far';
  }
  if($page == 3)
  {
     $html .= 'This page is under construction';
  }
  echo $html;
```

#### CSS:

```
.selected{background-color:red;}
```

In my case, I want to set the "Picutre" li as default page, and when user click on comments, it would load corresponding page. And also the background colour should also be changed.

Comment: Just call the function `show` with the right parameters when the document has finished loading …?

Answer (score 1):

Your page logic lives in your PHP, so specifying which page should display by default can be added there by modifying your `if` statements and making them into `if...else` instead:

```
if ($page==2) {
     $html .= 'No comments so far';
} else if ($page==3) {
     $html .= 'This page is under construction';
} else {
     $html .= '<img src="./product_images/'.$row["name"].'.jpg" width="150" border="2">';
}
```

The logic implemented above goes like this: if the "Comments" or "Others" pages are requested, serve them, but if not then just serve the "Pictures" page.

Since you also want to load the "Picture" content when the page is initially loaded, you can call the `show()` function in your Javascript on pageload.  Adding the following line to your existing `jQuery(document).ready(function () { ... }` should work as long as `$row["id"]` is properly set:

```
show($row["id"], 1);
```

Comment: Sorry, but in my case, the page is loaded when user click on the li. However, when users don't click on one of the li. How to set the Picture page as default one.

Comment: In other words, without clicking, the picture page would be displayed.

Comment: Sorry, by the way, how to set Picture li background color as selected basing on my JS? I mean, I want to make the pic li background as default one.

Comment: @user2295136 I've updated my answer to provide what I think you want.